# CSS element specific pseudo element

Tags: css, pseudo-element

This might not be the right place to ask this question, but I will ask anyway and somebody can move it if I have chosen the wrong place to post.

I have read about the various pseudo elements that can be used to style 'fake' elements that don't actually exist. I know that there are ones like ':before' and ':after'.

I also know that there are others that are used for specific elements, like `::input-placeholder`. Does anybody know of a reference that give details on all of the different pseudo elements, including those for specific elements?

I googled it and i can't find anything that does both the more 'generic' ones *and* the ones that are tied to a specific element.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp, and e.g. `::-webkit-input-placeholder` is used to style the HTML5 input placeholder attribute in Webkit: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/.

Comment: @snuffn: That page is absolutely terrible. It munges pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements together in a single page called `css_pseudo_elements.asp`... really W3Schools? Oh wait, it's W3Schools.

Comment: The annoying thing about pseudo-elements is that you're not going to find any of the new ones in the Selectors spec, since that spec only describes the selector syntax, as well as the pseudo-elements from CSS1 and 2. You'll only find the new ones... wherever. In various other CSS modules or even non-CSS documents. Because `::input-placeholder` is as you say an element-specific pseudo-element, I think it is somewhere in the HTML5 spec; I can't find it in any CSS module.

Comment: @BoltClock: I couldn't find anything about it: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html. I think that selector still has browser prefixes.

Comment: The thing is that there are other element specific ones like one that lets you style the green part of a `<meter>` or `<progress)` elements. And there must be more, but don't know them and I want to, so I asked this question.

Comment: @snuffn That reference does not cover the element specific ones

Comment: @Blender: Then maybe it hasn't been specced yet. See, this is why it's so annoying :/

Answer (score 2):

There is no authoritative list of all pseudo-elements in CSS3, or constructs of CSS3 in general, because CS3 itself is a moving target, a collection of modules of very varying maturity. The W3C maintains just collections of links to the modules:
http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work.en.html

The best compilation I’ve encountered is the [MDN CSS Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/CSS_Reference). But note that you need to follow the links to Mozilla and WebKit extensions, too, to find out what might be implemented in browsers.

In the specific case of `::input-placeholder`, such a pseudoelement does not exist even in the drafts, but there are vendor prefixed versions, see question [Change an input's HTML5 placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css).